# Who is the angel and why ascending?

Tags: revelation, angels

I have a question concerning ***Revelations 7:2***

> **I saw another angel ascending** from the East, having a seal of the living God. He called with a loud voice to the four angels who had been given power to harm the land and the sea.

Who is this angel and why does he ascend?

Answer (score 3):

While this angel goes unnamed, we can deduce a little bit from the context. The verse mentions that "he called with a loud voice to the four angels." This gives some indication of authority over the other angels.

Rev. 12:7 says "Michael and his angels fought against the dragon". Show that Michael the archangel has authority over the other angels. So we can deduce that the angel of chapter 7 is Michael of chapter 12.

As to why he is ascending, there is much speculation as to what this means but nothing substantial has been acknowledged.